# How to refresh ErrorDataReceived to process faster?

Tags: c#, process

I'm using sox.exe to play some audio files.
This is how I'm calling it:

```
SoxPlayer = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = Play,
        Arguments = arg,
        WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath + "\\bin\\"
    }
};
```

and this is the code that should be interpreting the StandardError output:

```
private void UpdatePlaybackTime(string output)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output)) return;
    if (!output.Contains("%") || !output.Contains("[")) return;
    var index1 = output.IndexOf("%", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
    var index2 = output.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var time = output.Substring(index1, index2 - index1).Trim();
    var times = time.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var seconds = Convert.ToDouble(times[0]) * 3600;
    seconds = seconds + (Convert.ToDouble(times[1]) * 60);
    seconds = seconds + (Convert.ToDouble(times[2]));
    if (seconds == 0 || seconds < PlaybackSeconds) return;
    PlaybackSeconds = seconds;
}
```

My goal is to get the playback time from the sox output as accurately as possible, rather than work (as I was doing before) with an internal timer that may lose sync with sox's own.

My first attempt was using this recommendation I found online:

```
SoxPlayer.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => UpdatePlaybackTime(args.Data);
SoxPlayer.Start();
SoxPlayer.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

This current code "works" in that I get the information I want, but it seems like UpdatePlaybackTime() is being called every 5 seconds or so. When it's called, the info obtained is accurate, but obviously I want to update the playback info several times per second, not every 5 seconds.

My understanding is that what is happening is that UpdatePlaybackTime is being called when the StandardError buffer gets full. I've tried calling SoxPlayer.BeginErrorReadLine() with my player timer but it says it's already running asynchronously. I've tried SoxPlayer.StandardError.DiscardBufferedData() but it throws an exception because of the asynchronous process that is ongoing.

So, how can I manage to capture the playback information how I need? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

After discussing this code and how it's not working because of buffering, I've also tried the following inside a separate BackgroundWorker thread, with the same result (i.e. updates only about every 5 seconds):

```
SoxPlayer.Start();
SoxTimer.RunWorkerAsync();

private void SoxTimer_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var sr = new StreamReader(SoxPlayer.StandardError.BaseStream);
    while (sr.Peek() > 0)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        UpdatePlaybackTime(line);
    }
}

private void SoxTimer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!SoxPlayer.HasExited)
    {
        SoxTimer.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

When this BackgroundWorker completes, it checks if SoxPlayer.HasExited, and if it hasn't, it runs again. This has the same effect as my first attempt. PlaybackSeconds is only getting updated about every 5 seconds, at which point it updates to the right time, and then the rest of the code that acts based on the PlaybackSeconds value works as well.

I also tried achieving the same by creating a Thread to work the reading of the StandardError output. Every instance results in the same, a 5 second or so delay between when UpdatePlaybackTime() gets called. When it does, it iterates through all the output that was sent to StandardError since the last time we iterated through it, so it then updates the PlaybackSeconds value very quickly in small increments and leaves it at the current value at that time. But again, one update as far as the user is concerned every 5 seconds.

Sox creators are adamant that the problem is not on their end. When played in a console window, output is constant. According to sox creators, every 0.1 seconds. If I tell sox to output is standarderror to a text file, the same happens. There's a constant updating of the information on the text file. Yet reading the StandardError stream itself, I have now spent the better part of two days with no acceptable results.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 2:

Following Peter's advice below, here's a brand new project. Didn't even change the default names for anything. Same behavior as described so far. So I'm going back to blame (ahem, discuss with) the SoX peeps.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Process SoxPlayer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bin = Application.StartupPath + "\\bin\\";

            SoxPlayer = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    FileName = bin + "sox.exe",
                    Arguments = "song.ogg -c 2 -d",
                    WorkingDirectory = bin
                }
            };

            SoxPlayer.Start();
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                int cch;
                var rgch = new char[1];

                while ((cch = SoxPlayer.StandardError.Read(rgch, 0, rgch.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    var cch1 = cch;
                    label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label1.Text = new string(rgch, 0, cch1)));
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoxPlayer.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to read the `StandardError` stream directly. You can use `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync()` if you want asynchronous handling. That said, even doing it that way might not address the issue; it depends on where the buffering is done, and assuming your process is actually generating stderr output more frequently than every 5 seconds, it's hard to see why .NET would delay receipt of that output, even for the sake of buffering.

Comment: It is buffered on the sox' end, nothing you can do about it in C#.  Modify sox by calling setvbuf() to reduce the buffer size or fflush() to force it to flush the buffer.

Comment: If I show the console window or run sox manually, there is no buffering. The standard error info is displayed immediately as it plays through the file. Are you saying there is buffering only when redirecting the standard error from the console window? Why?

Comment: @Peter Duniho, unfortunately I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 4.0, which doesn't seem to support ReadLineAsync() as far as I understand.

Comment: You're correct. That said, you can still read from the `StandardError` in a separate thread to achieve asynchronous behavior. Or even get the underlying `BaseStream`, which has the asynchronous `BeginRead()` method you could use (you'd have to decode the data explicitly, using an appropriate `Decoder` object). Personally, I'd just read from a separate thread, at least to see if it changes the behavior. But I suspect Hans' comment is correct, and you'll need to change the configuration of the process itself. Still, you might as well explore all your options. :)

Comment: Seem strange that a console app write status to stderror rather than stdout

Comment: @PeterDuniho, do you have an example of how to use a separated thread to access the standard error output? Never seen that before in my limited exposure.

Tien, it's how sox functions for some reason.

Comment: Reading from a different thread is just like reading in your main thread (e.g. `string line; while ((line = SoxPlayer.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null) { UpdatePlaybackTime(line); }`), except you create a new `Thread` instance for the purpose. See the [`Thread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Peter, I was able to move the code into it's own thread. I call the thread with one of my existing timers, in this case should be running 4 times per second. The code works, but again, the update is only happening after about 5 seconds worth. I don't have the source code for sox and considering how complex it is, I doubt I would be able to alter it without breaking it. I'll have to think of another way to accomplish this. It surely seems like a lot of work for nothing. DoNotCreateWindow=false means I see the exact info I want refresh multiple times per second. But somehow I can't capture it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I'm on the SoX mailing list, so I sent out a message asking for help. One of the main contributors to SoX responded with the following: "There is two possible bufferings here: - the buffering of the SoX stderr output; man setvbuf says "The standard error stream stderr is initially unbuffered." As SoX does not (AFAIG) set any buffering of the stderr output, this is not the case. - the buffering of your application's input. This is most likely the problem here. Your problem is not a SoX problem. There is nothing to do about this on the SoX side."
--- so I'm back to beginreadline();

Comment: If it's not SoX, then you can reproduce it with a short, simple code example. And if you can reproduce it with a short, simple code example, then that's what you should post here for advice. It is nearly impossible and unproductive to try to diagnose a problem without actual working code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho and anyone else who may want to help. I have edited the OP to include much more information and expand on what other things I've tried, along with including snippets of the code. Anything else that I'm not telling is simply because I don't know anymore than what I've tried and written down. I would highly appreciate a response that will lead to a solution. Maybe it shows how ignorant I am, but this seems like it should be a simple issue. Yet it's been obnoxiously difficult to narrow down.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, for posterity's sake I went ahead and moved this project to Visual Studio 2013 and to .NET Framework 4.5.1 so I could try ReadLineAsync() ... which turns out it's not truly working asynchronously (it has been documented with Microsoft) so the task worker fails to return until it finishes computing ... every 5 seconds or so :-D So even with ReadLineAsync() I get the same behavior. So as I said to the SoX people, I give up in trying to reach that output. Just thought I'd let ya know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not sure what you mean about `ReadLineAsync()` not working asynchronously. I know there's an issue with the `Console.In` object _specifically_, but `ReadLineAsync()` does work asynchronously _generally_. I've used it successfully myself with a `Process` object's output streams like you are here and it works fine. In any case, asynchronous or not, that wouldn't affect the _timing_ aspect (i.e. the 5-second intervals); it would just cause a particular thread to block until the read operation completed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple code example that *does not* reproduce the behavior you describe:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = "SimpleStderrWriter.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        process.Start();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int cch;
            char[] rgch = new char[1];

            Console.WriteLine("Reading stderr from process");

            while ((cch = process.StandardError.Read(rgch, 0, rgch.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(new string(rgch, 0, cch));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Process exited");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate process");
        thread.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine();
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `SimpleStderrWriter.exe` program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool exit = false;

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!Volatile.Read(ref exit))
            {
                Console.Error.Write('.');
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
        });

        thread.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Volatile.Write(ref exit, true);
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

This code example demonstrates clearly, by receiving and re-emitting the child process's stderr output as quickly as it's generated, that there is nothing in .NET that by default would cause the delay you are experiencing. The obvious conclusion is that either your advisors with respect to SoX are wrong and it does some buffering for some reason, or that you yourself have added something to your code that introduces the delay you are experiencing.

If you are positive the latter is not the case, then you need to go back to your SoX advisor and explain to them that they are mistaken. If you are positive that the SoX advisor is correct, then you need to post an example similar to the above, but which *does* reproduce the delay you are experiencing.

Comment: Peter, I copy/pasted your code sample (changing the Text in a label instead of writing to a console). Every 5 seconds or so, my time label displays the characters in the StandardError stream very quickly (I didn't even process them, just for testing), and then it stops, then another 5 seconds later, repeats.
I'm not sure how a console application is representative of the behavior of a windows form application. My process is called with "CreateNoWindow = true,", which yours isn't. I've disabled all my running processes on my program, still no change in behavior. Frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Peter, it seems you're right. I'm going to have to go back to the SoX people with some stronger language :-) See my Edit #2 on the OP. Brand new project and form, the code listed is the entirety of the thing. Still, same behavior I've described thus far. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is the Sox Mailing List archive for this issue, if you're curious.

http://sox.10957.n7.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-force-Sox-to-flush-the-standard-error-output-td5287.html

Comment: @TrojanNemo: in answer to your questions...  the console scenario should be reasonably comparable to the Winforms scenario. Of course, you can confirm this by testing your Winforms version with the little test app I've provided here (i.e. instead of using the SoX program). As for `CreateNoWindow`, that also shouldn't make a difference; it's not needed for the console version, because the same console window is reused (i.e. no window is created in any case). But again, if it does make a difference, this is easily tested.

Comment: @TrojanNemo: FYI, I tested the Winforms scenario myself, using `CreateNoWindow = true;`, and it works fine. As expected, there's no material difference between doing the test in a console vs Winforms app.

Comment: Oh, and...to the curmudgeon who down-voted: if you have a better suggestion for how to present the answer that "the issue must be outside of .NET", including relevant code examples to support that answer, I'm all ears. Down-voting without feedback isn't very constructive.

Comment: Peter, don't know who downvoted, wasn't me! Thanks for your time. I created my own console application to output current time every 100ms based on your suggested test code. On my test form, I put the Thread to read the stream inside a timer. The timer runs every 100ms. My form displays the output from my test console application in real time. Only changing the application name and argument from "test_timer.exe" to "sox.exe" and from "" to "song.ogg -c 2 -d" takes me back to the same behavior I've experienced all this time. Change it back to "test_timer.exe", expected behavior. So it's SoX.

Comment: @TrojanNemo: Glad the sample code could help. Feel free to add a vote if you found my answer useful/helpful. I get enough upvotes elsewhere that the odd -2 doesn't really matter, but it's still a bit annoying. An offsetting upvote eases the annoyance factor a bit, especially when it's honest. :)

Comment: Peter, apparently I can't upvote because of low reputation. But I marked your answer as the answer to my question, since I suppose it does answer it. Thanks.